# It there a way to put flowcharts into the code for documentation i Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, documentation, visual-studio-2019, flowchart

I have parts of my code that I've drawn as flowcharts to help me program and document it.
It would be nice if there was a way to document this inside the Visual Studio IDE. Is this somehow possible?

I don't need to have the code auto-generated based on a flowchart or have an auto-generated flowchart based on code. It's enough simply to have the documentation feature at hand while working in the IDE.

Comment: For older VS versions there was https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MsBishop.ImageComments&ssr=false#overview

Comment: @SergeyVlasov - thanks a million ! Your comment send me in the right direction.
For Visual Studio 2019 I found an extention called "Memeful Comments". I'll give that a test and see if that will do the trick.